# SQL Server MERGE, if exist then update else insert

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, merge

I've a table called `data` with columns `ip, report_date, group, value`. The primary key is `ip`, `report_date` and `group` together.

When the table is empty and I run the statement below there is nothing inserted. What's wrong with my statement?

When there is a match the record is updates according plan...

```
MERGE bc_data2 AS Target
USING (SELECT ip, report_date, group, value FROM bc_data2 As b
WHERE b.ip = '1.1.1.2'
AND b.report_date = '2/29/2012'
AND b.group = 'EPO-Client-Update') AS Source
ON (Target.ip = Source.ip
AND Target.frequency = Source.frequency
AND Target.report_date = Source.report_date
AND Target.service = Source.service
AND Target.proxy_service = Source.proxy_service
AND Target.proxy = Source.proxy
AND Target.service_group = Source.service_group)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET Target.value = Target.value + 1
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY Target THEN
    INSERT (ip, report_date, group, value)
    VALUES ('1.1.1.2', '2/29/2012', 'EPO-Client-Update', 119437142);
```

Comment: Something quick to try - take out `BY Target`? Also are you doing this inside `TRY/CATCH`? Is there a trigger on `bc_data2`? Maybe there is an error or intentional rollback that you're not seeing.

Comment: i'm trying the statement directly in server management studio. removing 'by target' doesn't make any difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't add any rows because your `using` clause is not returning any rows. Put your constants in the `using` clause with column aliases and use the fields in the `when not matched`

Something like this with a couple of fields removed simplicity.

```
merge bc_data2 as T
using (select '1.1.1.2' as ip,
              '2012-02-29' as report_date,
              1194370142 as value) as S
on T.ip = S.ip and
   T.report_date = S.report_date
when matched then
  update set T.value = T.value + 1
when not matched then
  insert (ip, report_date, value) 
    values(ip, report_date, value);
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found that `NULLs` don't compare well in the `ON` clause of the `MERGE` statement. However, converting `NULLs` to blanks is a valid workaround. I would modify the the `ON` statement to look something like this.

```
ON (ISNULL(Target.ip, '')           = ISNULL(Source.ip, '')
AND ISNULL(Target.frequency, '')    = ISNULL(Source.frequency, '')
AND ISNULL(Target.report_date, '')  = ISNULL(Source.report_date, '')
AND ...)
```